# How to capture the values using regular expressions?

Tags: python, regex

I have this string

```
circle,4.5
square,3.1
circle,2.0
triangle,4.7,4.9
square,4.1
circle,4.3
```

Lets say I want to capture The name of the shape and the two numbers next to it. I've tried this and will comment about the issue i have inside it:

```
>>> ma = re.search(r"(\w+)[,(\d+.\d+)]+", "Triangle,3.4,1.2")
>>> ma.group()
'Triangle,3.4,1.2'
>>> ma.group(1)
'Triangle'
>>> ma.group(2)  ##Why is this happening ???
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#29>", line 1, in <module>
    ma.group(2)
IndexError: no such group
```

I guess i can't put capturing groups inside square brackets ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Square brackets are special; they mark all characters inside of them as a character group. You are asking to match either a number (`\d`), a `,` comma, a `.` full stop, a `(` opening parenthesis or a `)` closing parenthesis. In other words, the opening and closing parenthesis are part of the matched characters, *not* denoting a capturing group.

You don't need to use a character class at all here, you are looking for a more specific pattern of number, follewed by a full stop followed by another number. Use a non-capturing group (`(?:...)`) to group the number format together with the comma to match repeating groups of numbers:

```
r"(\w+)(?:,(\d+.\d+))+"
```

Unfortunately, this still won't capture more than one group for you; regular expressions will never produce a variable number of groups. We've defined only two group here, so that's all we get:

```
>>> import re
>>> ma = re.search(r"(\w+)(?:,(\d+.\d+))+", "Triangle,3.4,1.2")
>>> ma.groups()
('Triangle', '1.2')
```

See [Regex question about parsing method signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493844/regex-question-about-parsing-method-signature) and [python regex repetition with capture question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6673686/python-regex-repetition-with-capture-question) for other SO questions that ran into this limitation.

Your format is actually very simple, and you'd be much better off *not* using regular expressions at all. Simply split by the `,` comma and be done with it:

```
>>> "Triangle,3.4,1.2".split(',')
['Triangle', '3.4', '1.2']
```

Answer (score 1):

Square brackets have special meaning. They are meant to create `Character class`.. So, if you put `capture groups` inside square brackets, it means, match **group1, or group2, or group3**.. It will not match all the groups in continuity.. You would have to use another `capture group` in place of square bracket..

But, you can simply use split for this case: -

```
>>> str = "Triangle,3.4,1.2"
>>> str.split(",")
['Triangle', '3.4', '1.2']
>>> 
>>> str = "circle,4.5"
>>> str.split(",")
['circle', '4.5']

>>> str.split(",")[0]
'circle'
>>> str.split(",")[1]
'4.5'
```

As per your regex: -

```
ma = re.search(r"(\w+)[,(\d+.\d+)]+", "Triangle,3.4,1.2")
```

You are using character set `[,(\d+.\d+)]`, which matches - `,` or `(\d+.\d+)`..

You should change it to: -

```
ma = re.search(r"(\w+)(,(\d+.\d+))+", "Triangle,3.4,1.2")
```

But there is a problem in this case: -

**You have created only 3 groups: -**

```
group 0 -> complete match
group 1 -> `,1.2` (Outer bracket)
group 2 -> `1.2`  (Inner Bracket)
```

You will not get `3.4` because `(,(\d+.\d+))` first matches - `,3.4` and then `,1.2`.. So, it only remembers `,1.2`..

Answer (score 1):

Using `.split(',')` is the most easy way, however, if you want to use regex, then you should use

```
ma = re.search(r"^([^,]+),([^,]+)(?:,([^,]+))?", "Triangle,3.4,1.2")
```